# System.Object[] - when file names are same

Tags: powershell, csv

I have files in E:\MyFiles\ and E:\MyFiles\August. I am using PowerShell to store the file paths in a csv file (E:\CSVPaths.csv).

This is my script:

```
$exclude = @(".html", ".tt", ".xaml", ".csproj", ".sln", ".xml", ".cmd", ".txt",".svn")
"DirectoryPath, SourceFileName" | Out-File -FilePath "E:\CSVPaths.csv" -Encoding ASCII 
$table = (get-childitem -recurse "E:\MyFiles" -File -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Where-Object { $exclude -notcontains $_.Extension }).Fullname 
foreach ($row in $table)
{
  $file=Get-ChildItem -recurse $row
  $fileObject = new-object PSObject
  $fileObject | add-member -membertype NoteProperty -name "DirectoryPath" -Value  $file.DirectoryName 
  $fileObject | add-member -membertype NoteProperty -name "SourceFileName" -Value  $file.Name 
  $newrow=$fileObject
  Export-Csv "E:\CSVPaths.csv" -inputobject $newrow -append -Force
}
```

In both E:\MyFiles and E:\MyFiles\August folders, there are files with same name (example: Audit_Report.csv). While exporting to csv they are stored as `System.Object[]` in `DirectoryPath` and `SourceFileName` which is shown below:

```
DirectoryPath      SourceFileName

System.Object[]     System.Object[] 
E:\MyFiles\August   Audit_Report.csv
```

Please help to fix this issue.

Comment: _shell script_? You mean PowreShell?

Comment: @Clijsters: Powershell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to use a loop to get the output your after [AFAICS](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/AFAICS).

```
$exclude = @(".html", ".tt", ".xaml", ".csproj", ".sln", ".xml", ".cmd", ".txt",".svn")
"DirectoryPath, SourceFileName" | Out-File -FilePath "E:\CSVPaths.csv" -Encoding ASCII 

Get-ChildItem -recurse "E:\MyFiles" -File -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue |
    Where-Object { $exclude -notcontains $_.Extension } |
    Select-Object @{n="SoureFileName";e={$_.Name}},@{n="DirectoryPath";e={$_.DirectoryName}} |
    Export-csv "E:\CSVPaths.csv" -Force -NoTypeInformation
    # NB: The "-NoTypeInformation" is an assumption - remove if you what type info.
```

Comment: Perfect. Working great. Thank you.